# Python--Export Parsed XML to txt file using

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing text from an XML file. Parsing works well, and I can print the results in full, but when I try to write the text into a text document, all I get in the document is the last item.

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib.request
 import sys

 req = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Dow%20Jones/compaq%20neg%201.xml')

 xml = BeautifulSoup(req, 'xml')

 for item in xml.findAll('paragraph'):
     sys.stdout = open('CN1.txt', 'w')
     print(item.text)
     sys.stdout.close()
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Overwriting `sys.stdout`, while supported, is... an unusual choice. Is there a reason you aren't storing the file handle under a different name, then using `f.write()` or similar?

Comment: BTW, there's nothing XML-specific about this question. It could, for instance, be simplified to `for item in ["hello", "cruel", "world"]:` with no XML-related code present at all, and you'd still have the same behavior (only the last string you were iterating over present in your output file).

Comment: I'm brand new to working with XML and writing from python. I've done similar with R, but not python.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are opening the file every time you go through the loop, which I am surprised it let you do.  When it opens the file, it is is opening it in write mode and therefore is wiping out everything that was in it on the last pass through the loop.

Comment: Why's it surprising? Even if it weren't doing an explicit close, any POSIXy platform lets a file be concurrently open for write by more than one process unless explicit locking steps are taken.

Comment: It has been a very long time since I coded on anything that could be called POSIXy.  I just assumed doing that would generate an error, since I was taught this was a bad thing to do (in general).  Thanks for the info.